# Call javascript function by clicking on HTML list element

Tags: javascript, html, menu

I am new to web development so this question may be too obvious to others. I would like to make a menu, when menu item is clicked it needs to call javascript function with one argument, the item id. I would like to present menu items as a unnumbered list. What I do not understand is how to bind the same function to each list item, which will be generated by server-side php script.

Comment: if you are web developer then you should know that you can add lines in echo or print code onclick function or use jquery for click function on ul li

Comment: Something like document.getElementsByTagName("li").addEventListener("click", myScript);

Comment: @M.chaury , he said he is new to web dev.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will hopefully get you going in the right direction. All I'm doing is binding an "onClick" event listener to all `li` elements, you might want to change what you bind to in case you use them elsewhere. Then when they are clicked they call the function `myScript` which get's their ID and alerts it.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k89Ax/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li id="1">Link 1</li>
    <li id="2">Link 2</li>
    <li id="3">Link 3</li>
    <li id="4">Link 4</li>
    <li id="5">Link 5</li>
</ul
```

**Javascript**

```
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(var i = 0;i<li.length;i++){
    li[i].addEventListener("click", myScript);
}

function myScript(e){
    alert(e.target.attributes.id.value);       
}
```